# Como fazer o método prepareForSegue esperar um determinado processamento terminar para ser chamado?

Tags: ios, swift, thread, uiviewcontroller

Ao clicar em um determinado botão eu faço uma consulta no firebase para retornar dados, no entanto esse mesmo botão chama outra view controller, e o problema está ai, a view controller é chamada antes do firebase retornar todos os dados, e consequentemente os valores são passados como nil. Estava pensando em gerenciamento de thread (pausar determinada thread) ou algo do tipo, mais não sei se é isso. Existe alguma maneira de eu executar o método prepareForSegue somente após o termino de um determinado processamento ?

Comment: Seria mais interessante 'agendar' na fila de processos do iOS, dentro do viewcontroller já chamado essa execução deveria ficar no `onDidLoad()`. Coloque o código que vc já tem na pergunta. Qual versão do swift usa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

- Remova o Segue existente que foi criado a partir do botão
- Crie um novo segue arrastando o ícone amarelo do controller de origem até o controller de destino
- Clique no segue criado e dê um Identifier para ele pela aba Attributes Inspector, por exemplo `ExibeDados`
- Depois do retorno dos dados do Firebase, execute o seguinte código:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "ExibeDados", sender: nil)
```

Dessa forma o segue não é chamado automaticamente ao clicar no botão e você pode chamá-lo quando quiser.

Comment: Fiz isso que me falou e deu certo, simples de resolver. Muito Obrigado !